# Mongodump with tunnel-ssh throwing ECONNRESET error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh-tunnel, mongodump

I am creating a backup using `mongodump` from a remote mongo server. The remote mongo requires a private key so I cannot directly run the `mongodump` command directly. I need to create a ssh tunnel to the server first. My ssh tunneling works fine in the code below since I have tested it by querying on remote mongo.

The issue is when I run the `mongodump` query, the dump is created fine but just as the query finish I get this ECONNRESET error below

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:208:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

My code snippet looks like this:

```
const sshConfig = {
  username: process.env.BACKUP_MONGO_USER,
  port: 22,
  dstPort: 27017,
  localPort: 27018,
  host: process.env.BACKUP_MONGO_HOST,
  dstHost: '127.0.0.1',
  localHost: '127.0.0.1',
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync(process.env.BACKUP_MONGO_FILE),
  keepAlive: true,
};

const connection = new Promise((resolve, _) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  tunnel(sshConfig,
    async (err, server) => {
      resolve({ server });
    },
  );
});

async function dbDump() {
  const { server } = await connection;
  console.log('Connection Successful');
  const command = `mongodump --db <dbName> --collection <collectionName> --host localhost --port 27018`;
  exec(command,
    (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if(err) { console.log('err', err); }
      if(stderr) { console.log('stderr', stderr); }
      if(stdout) { console.log('stdout', stdout); }
      server.close();
    });

}

dbDump();
```

Comment: Does it give the same error if you comment out `server.close()`

Comment: @Joe, yes, it still throws the same error

Comment: You might check the server log to see if it complains about anything.

Comment: @Joe, do you know where to look for these logs?
I took a look at /var/ssh/auth.log, that just gave session open and close. is there anywhere else you think I should look at. And thank you for your responses so far

Comment: The log path would be in the mongod conf file, or on the command line depending on how you started the server.